# FLASK_APP for Quart

Tags: python, quart

I've very interested in taking advantage of some of the async mechanisms available in [Quart](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/). 
Larger Flask apps can be laid out in [packages](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/packages/), mine are too.

They then require a `FLASK_APP` environment variable to be set with the name of that package.

Is there an equivalent way to do this with a Quart app? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A few minutes after posting this, I've found it

```
QUART_APP=your_package
```